# Integrate function with variable in multiple arguments using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

If you have a function f(x,a,b), you can provide values for a and b using the args parameter of scipy's quad function.  What if you have a function with x in multiple places eg. f(x,ax,bx)?

For example, I'd like to integrate `norm.cdf(1,a*x,b*x**.5)` for some set values of a and b.  So far, I've been able to make it work with:

```
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import norm
a=1
b=2
integrate.quad(lambda x:norm.cdf(1,a*x,b*x**.5),0,1)
```

Is that the only way to do it, or is there some built in functionality for using the variable of integration in multiple arguments?

Comment: norm.cdf, with mean and variance proportional to x (see the example code above).

Comment: You'll need to write a function that conforms the first case, with `a` and `b` constants that are passed via the `args` parameter.  Use the regular function definition syntax to make it easier to develop and test.  And test the function for some `x` in the (0,1) range.

Comment: What you've done is fine.  @hpaulj's suggestion would also work, but your use of a lambda expression (which captures the variables `a` and `b` in a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))) is a standard technique for creating a callable to be passed to a function like `quad`.